# Дубликаты ссылок в Похожие

Tags: поддержка, предложение, похожие-вопросы

Предлагаю чтобы ссылки на Связанные вопросы не грузились в блок Похожие.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылку бы на пример...

Comment: @Qwertiy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823513/Загрузка-видимых-картинок-Ленивая-загрузка-картинок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По этой ситуации заведен старинный [баг-репорт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48624/339911), отмеченный при этом в феврале 2011 года меткой [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). То есть администрация на тот момент решила ничего не менять и считать имеющееся поведение корректным.

Для резолюции по вашему предложению стоит посмотреть имеющиеся ответы на MSE. Можно заметить, что если связанные вопросы перестать отображать в списке похожих, то мы потеряем информацию о том, что вопросы действительно похожи (на основании алгоритмов, которые формируют этот список), а не просто кем-то связаны, упоминанием ссылок. В такой ситуации более правильным будет предложенный вариант с появлением нового списка «связанные и похожие». Это как исключит дублирование, так и сохранит информацию о причине группировки нескольких вопросов.